# TryFromIntError usage

Tags: rust

I unable to use `std::num::TryFromIntError` as the default error in my `TryFrom` implementation. Is this issue to be expected or is it a documentation issue / bug.

```
#![feature(try_from)]
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::num::TryFromIntError;

enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

impl TryFrom<u16> for OpCode {
    type Error = TryFromIntError;
    fn try_from(val: u16) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match val {
            0 => Ok(MyEnum::A),
            1 => Ok(MyEnum::B),
            2 => Ok(MyEnum::C),
            _ => Err(TryFromIntError),
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation fails with:

```
error[E0423]: expected function, found struct `TryFromIntError`
  --> src/main.rs:18:22
   |
18 |             _ => Err(TryFromIntError()),
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ constructor is not visible here due to private fields
```

Answer (score 4):

`TryFromIntError` is a tuple struct with private fields (hence the `(_)` in the documentation). The type doesn't expose any way to construct an instance (such as a `new` method or a `Default` implementation), therefore there is no way to instantiate the type directly. Perhaps the reason is to leave open the possibility to add details to the error in the future (right now, the only private field is a `()`, thus the error has no details).

Comment: so what is a good error type to use, instead, in these types of situations? Just `std::error::Error`?